# Unit test to check retrievals from config file

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

In a spark project we use Typesafe Config. We have a big config file with some (necessary) redundancy. It is quite easy to refer the wrong branch of the config json and sometimes the error slips to production code.

I need to verify that all the calls of config.getString(x) with x literal will not fail for a given config file.
I'd like to write a unit test that checks every string used in my application to obtain a config value.

A possible solution we found is to preload all the config values to a case class, so

```
val rawPath = config.getString("comp1.data.files.rawData")
val coresNumber = config.getLong("comp1.setup.cores")
```

would become

```
case class ConfigData(rawPath:String, coresNumber:Long)
def initConfig():ConfigData ={
    val rawPath = config.getString("comp1.data.files.rawData")
    val coresNumber = config.getLong("comp1.setup.cores") 
    ConfigData(rawPat,coresNumber)
}

val conf = initConfig()
val rawPath = conf.rawPath
val coresNumner = conf.coresNumber
```

and then simply call `initData()` to test for config load errors.

I've also thought of using scala reflection but I'd need to find all the places in my code where `config.getString(x)` is called and then obtain the `x` to test their existence in the config file, but I can't find a way to get all the instances of a method call and create a test on the parameter.

Is there anything I haven't thought of?

Comment: what do you mean by get all the instances ? you want to test if all tout config files don't contain errors ?

Comment: No, I need to verify that all the calls of config.getString(x) with x literal will not fail for a given config file. Thanks for the comment, I'll update my question

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to provide the configuration in a Singleton, which you initialise when starting the server - so the Server starts only if the configuration is correct. Or run the configurations in Unit Tests.

In this Singleton you load your Configuration in single `values` or `case classes` depending on amount of values.

We use [pureconfig](https://pureconfig.github.io) which makes it pretty simple to map the configuration directly into `case classes`.

Here is an Example without *Pure Script*: [DemoAdapterContext](https://github.com/pme123/scala-adapters/blob/master/server/app/pme123/adapters/server/entity/demo/DemoAdapterContext.scala) and [AdaptersContext](https://github.com/pme123/scala-adapters/blob/master/server/app/pme123/adapters/server/entity/AdaptersContext.scala).

Let me know if you need more infos.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about pureconfig, I'll look into it. If possible however I'd rather not change much of my code while adding pureconfig would make me do that

Comment: see the link - with an example from an older Project without Pure Script - it also logs the config on startup